# Zend and jQuery DatePicker producing unexpected result

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Zend form, for which I have enabled jQuery components via:

```
ZendX_JQuery::enableForm($this);
```

and then added several non-jQuery elements, and one jQuery DatePicker, defined as:

```
$testing = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('dp1', array('jQueryParams' => array('dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd')));
$testing->setLabel('Date of Birth 2')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```

I then set up the Decorators as follows (first for all the elements, and then replaced the Decorator definition for the DatePicker):

```
$this->clearDecorators();
$this->addDecorator('FormElements')
    ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'form-block'))
    ->addDecorator('Form');

$this->setElementDecorators(array(
    array('ViewHelper'),
    array('Errors'),
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'tooltip')),
    array('Label', array('separator'=>' ')),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'element-block')),
));

$formJQueryElements = array(
    array('UiWidgetElement', array('tag' => '')),
    array('Errors'),
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'tooltip')),
    array('Label', array('separator' => ' ')),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element-block')),
);
$this->getElement('dp1')->clearDecorators();
$this->getElement('dp1')->setDecorators($formJQueryElements);
```

This seems to display all my fields correctly, with the exception of the DatePicker, which has somehow been converted into a text field. The HTML for the field looks like:

```
<div class="element-block">
    <label for="dp1" class="required">Date of Birth 2</label> 
    <input type="text" name="dp1" id="dp1" value="">
</div>
```

which is not a DatePicker. What have I missed in setting this up, or what error have I made here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, at least partially. I forgot to include the following code in my view, which meant that the field did not get converted into a date field:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#dp1").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

which changes the text field into a DatePicker. But this does not retain any of the jQuery options set in the Form class, which means I either have to set them here, which will only work if all datepickers on the site use the same rules for display (which they do not), and I have to change from using the ID to using the class of the element, which is not a big deal.